# Having VS 2012 installed but not .Net 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

when i install VS 2012, .Net 4.5 is automatically installed. 
I do not want 4.5 installed.
Is it possible to run VS 2012 on machine that only has .NET 4.0?

Comment: It would be strange if (the managed part of) VS2012 didn't use  the new Fx.

Comment: What's the point of this? Do you just want the new Metr— ahem, Modern UI look? That's not a very good reason to upgrade your entire IDE and just your entire IDE.

Comment: I presume this is a question asking how to use VS2012 without the [known issue](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3127346-support-a-net-4-0-service-pack-on-windows-xp-supp) around targeting .NET 4.0?

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 requires .NET 4.5 to be installed.  Visual Studio 2010 requires .NET 4.0 to be installed.   Visual Studio 2008 requires .NET 3.5 to be installed.

Comment: Because 4.5 replaces 4. They cannot be run side by side. Its supposed to be backwars compabtible but they are not. For example our project does not build after I have installed VS 2012. This is because 4.5 is only backwars comp. in some cases...

Comment: There are cases where you would need VS2012, for example due to the new much improved XAML editors.  But since .NET 4.5 is not perfectly backward compatible with .NET 4 you may not want to have .NET 4.5 installed.

Comment: Why would this question be closed?!? It's a valid question with some good answers.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to run VS 2012 on machine that only has .NET 4.0?

I'd be very surprised if that were the case, given that large portions of Visual Studio are written in .NET. I haven't checked, but I'd fully expect them to have references to .NET 4.5 assemblies and use features only available in .NET 4.5.

I suggest you have a separate virtual machine for .NET 4 testing.

Comment: I can confirm that VS2012 fails to run if .NET 4.5 is removed.  Unfortunately some people (like myself) are unable to run on .NET 4.5 since I have some references to third party assemblies that blow due to differences in how statics are initialized in .NET 4.5 vs 4

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to have to uninstall VS 2012 and Windows 8 because for the first time 4.5 replaces 4.0 instead of running side by side.  I don't think it is possible to run genuine 4.0 once you install 2012 or switch to Windows 8.  Check the c:\windows\microsoft.net\framwork folders for yourself after 4.5 is installed.  4.5 dlls replace 4.0.

Probably going to have to keep windows 7 and .net 4.0 around a long long time just like IE 6.0 for business stuff.